# "GeofencingAPI is deprecated"

Tags: android, android-geofence

What should I replace this with? Also, I am targeting Android 7.0 for this Geofence App.

```
private void addNewGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GEOFENCE: Adding new Geofence.");
    if (checkPermissions()){
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient, request, createGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `GeofencingClient`.

Answer (score 5):

The version of Android you are using is not related to the use of the deprecated `GeofencingApi`. The `GeofencingApi` is part of Google Play Services and was deprecated in release 11.0.

At this time the alternative `GeofencingClient` was added to Google Play Services.

You therefore no longer need to set up a `GoogleApiClient` in order to access the Geofencing API. Just set up a Geofencing client, then call it in a similar way to your previous call. The main difference is that you do not have to implement a result callback, you can add whichever success/failure/completed callback you require.

So for your code it would be...

```
client = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient;
...
client.addGeofences(request, createGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // your success code
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // your fail code;
                        }
                    });
```

Note you would still need to check your permissions before calling this code.

See [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) for a fuller explanation.

Comment: I've been working with geoFencingClient for a while. The Google example doesn't bother to show what to do within the onFailure() - but I know from practical experience that it DOES sometimes fail to add a geofence. Why? I know the limit is 100 but even just on the 2nd addition it can fail. Why ?